# Gradle Custom Task Configuration

Tags: gradle

I'm working on a Gradle plugin that has a Custom Task with two member variables that I would like to initialize using an extension class. I am extending the plugin class as follows:

```
class CustomPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

  @Override void apply(Project project) {
    def extension = project.extensions.create("Custom", CustomExtension)

    project.task("doTask", type: CustomTask, {
      group = "Awesome"
      description = "Runs a custom routine"
      filePath = extension.filePath
      name = extension.name
    })
  }
}
```

Is this the proper way to initialize a Task that extends DefaultTask? I'm trying to understand if initialization is done in CustomPlugin or if within the CustomTask one would use:

```
 @TaskAction void removeUnusedResources() {
    String filePath = project.Custom.lintXmlFilePath
    String name = project.Custom.ignoreResFiles

    // Proceed with the task action
}
```

Only the second approach seems to work for me. One common pattern I am noticing in other plugins is that tasks tend to be defined within the plugin using `project.task("taskName") << { // task actions here}` instead of creating a separate class that extends DefaultTask. What is the right convention and where can I find more information?

Comment: I recommend to check answers to similar questions here and on http://forums.gradle.org.

Comment: Hello Peter, I'm having trouble finding a response on here or the gradle forums. Here is the link to the plugin: https://github.com/marcoRS/lint-cleaner-plugin/tree/master/src/main/groovy/com/droidtitan/lintcleaner Basically I am using a closure in a build.gradle script to initialize the CustomTask. Is this the right way of doing things? I'm not sure in this case why I would need an extension class.